# Does this sequence of function converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I was practicing for my final and stumbled on this problem.

Let $f_n$:$[0,1]$ $\mapsto$ $R$ such that

$f(x)_n$ =
\begin{cases}
nx,  &  0\leq \text{ $x$ } \lt1/n\\
1, & 1/n\leq\text{ $x$ }\leq 1
\end{cases}

I could find its piecewise limit, which is

$f(x)$ =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{ $x$ =0}  \\
1, & \text{ $otherwise$ }
\end{cases}

I was thinking about using the $sup$$|f(x)_n-f(x)|<\epsilon$

then I realized there were more than one interval of both $f_n$ and $f$.

So I used $x$ to indicate the supremum of each interval

for $x=0$

Clearly   $sup$$|f(x)_n-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$

Since both function yield $0$

for $1/n\leq\text{ $x$ }\leq 1$

Clearly   $sup$$|f(x)_n-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$

Since both function yield $1$

Now I am stuck here

for $0\lt \text{ $x$ } \lt1/n$

What should i do with this interval?

And does $f(x)_n$ converges uniformly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some theorems under your belt, you know that this sequence of functions cannot converge uniformly, since each $f_n$ is continuous but $f$ is not. On the interval you are considering, try and take a **very** small neighborhood of $0$, say $(0,\epsilon/n^2)$, and consider the difference between $f_n$ and $f$ on that subinterval.

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about that! Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Atchanaphong You're welcome!

Comment: One more question, if you would answer. On that subinterval $(0,ϵ/n^2)$ I find that its supremum of difference would be $1$ since I can choose $x$ to be as close to $0$ as possible, no matter how large $n$ is, so $nx$ goes to $0$.  Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Atchanaphong Yup!

Answer (score -1):

The sequence *doesn't* converge uniformly, since the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is again a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about this since I was focusing on the supremum.